# Function on dataframe rows to reduce duplicate pairs Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I've got a dataframe that looks like:

```
0     1      2      3       4       5       6       7      8     9     10     11
12    13     13     13.4    13.4    12.4    12.4    16     0     0     0      0
14    12.2   12.2   13.4    13.4    12.6    12.6    19     5     5     6.7    6.7
.
.
.
```

Each 'layer'/row has pairs that are duplicates that I want to reduce.

The one problem is that there are repeating 0s as well so I cannot just simply remove duplicates per row or it will leave an uneven number of rows.

My desired output would be a **lambda function** that I could apply to all rows of this dataframe to get this:

```
0     1      2      3       4       5      6 
12    13     13.4   12.4    16      0      0
14    12.2   13.4   12.6    19      5      6.7
.
.
.
```

Is there a simple function I could write to do this?

Comment: transpose + duplicated?

Comment: Are the repeats always consecutive columns?

Comment: The repeats occur in pairs for each row but may vary between rows so the rows that have unique values are not always in the same spot.

Comment: are the headers important? meaning, should columns have those exact values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Method 1 using [`transpose`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html)

As mentioned by Yuca in the comments:

```
df = df.T.drop_duplicates().T
df.columns = range(len(df.columns))

print(df)
      0     1     2     3     4    5    6
0  12.0  13.0  13.4  12.4  16.0  0.0  0.0
1  14.0  12.2  13.4  12.6  19.0  5.0  6.7
```

## Method 2 using `list comprehension` with even numbers

We can make a list of *even* numbers and then select those columns based on their index:

```
idxcols = [x-1 for x in range(len(df.columns)) if x % 2]

df = df.iloc[:, idxcols]

df.columns = range(len(df.columns))
```

---

```
print(df)
    0     1     2     3  4    5
0  12  13.0  13.4  12.4  0  0.0
1  14  12.2  13.4  12.6  5  6.7
```

Comment: @HelloToEarth, the first method will drop values that are duplicated, regardless of position (unclear if this is a requirement, just pointing it out). For example, if you had a column `12` that has the same values as column `1`, column `12` would be dropped even though it's not sequential to column `1`.

Comment: Yes I just found this out. Sorry I need to clarify that I want only **pairs** that are side-by-side duplicates to be removed (not all duplicates in the row). This includes the 0s that are found on the end. These methods do not keep the zeroes.

Comment: @HelloToEarth [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56044654/5858851) should work.

Answer (score 1):

In your case

```
from itertools import zip_longest
l=[sorted(set(x), key=x.index) for x in df.values.tolist()]
newdf=pd.DataFrame(l).ffill(1)
newdf
Out[177]: 
      0     1     2     3     4    5    6
0  12.0  13.0  13.4  12.4  16.0  0.0  0.0
1  14.0  12.2  13.4  12.6  19.0  5.0  6.7
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `functools.reduce` to sequentially concatenate columns to your output DataFrame if the next column is not equal to the last column added:

```
from functools import reduce
output_df = reduce(
    lambda d, c: d if (d.iloc[:,-1] == df[c]).all() else pd.concat([d, df[c]], axis=1),
    df.columns[1:],
    df[df.columns[0]].to_frame()
)
print(output_frame)
#    0     1     3     5   7  8   10
#0  12  13.0  13.4  12.4  16  0  0.0
#1  14  12.2  13.4  12.6  19  5  6.7
```

This method also maintains the column names of the columns which were picked, if that's important.

Assuming this is your input `df`:

```
print(df)
#    0     1     2     3     4     5     6   7  8  9   10   11
#0  12  13.0  13.0  13.4  13.4  12.4  12.4  16  0  0  0.0  0.0
#1  14  12.2  12.2  13.4  13.4  12.6  12.6  19  5  5  6.7  6.7
```